# Where do I find the Alfresco log files?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

In Alfresco server have disappeared several uploads, I check the log to see what happened to the files.

```
In /opt/alfresco/tomcat/logs
```

But the files are empty.

Comment: What version of Alfresco? How did you install it? Where did you install it? What runtime? etc

Comment: @Gagravarr I installed 4.0e its a server of production in www.

Comment: Installed how? With what? What runtime? What application server? Where? There's a whole host of ways of installing and running Alfresco, currently you're barely more than saying "sometimes my computer doesn't work correctly"....

Answer (score 4):

In the command line, try

```
$ ps axww | grep atalina.startup | grep -v ' atalin' | awk '{print $1}'
29047
$ ls -l /proc/29047/fd
```

replacing 29047 with your output.

That should give you all open files with their full path. Look for `catalina.out` and `alfresco.log`. Those should be there by default.

Comment: Says:

`alfresco 17165  4.0 47.8 12013016 2924752 ?    Sl   05:46   6:00 /opt/alfresco-4.0.e/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/alfresco-4.0.e/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -server -Xss1024K -Xms1G -Xmx8G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:NewSize=512M -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/alfresco-4.0.e/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/alfresco-4.0.e/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/alfresco-4.0.e/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/alfresco-4.0.e/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/alfresco-4.0.e/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.star`

Comment: take a look at /opt/alfresco-4.0.e/tomcat/logs/catalina.out & /home/alfresco/alfresco.log

Comment: I wish Alfresco would change alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties   to read "log4j.appender.File.File=${catalina.home}/logs/alfresco.log".  As is, you never know where alfresco.log ends up. I change that every time, and thats quite annoying. :) Would be even better if the logfile localtion could be configured externally.

Answer (score 1):

It dependes, which logs you mean, there are 3 or 4 basic log files:

- Alfresco log
- Share log
- "indexator" log (Solr/Lucene)
- Tomcat log

For Community edition installed from installator you can find locations there

- `./tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties` (logs for
  Alfresco share)
- `./tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties` (logs for
  alfresco)
- `./solr4/log4j-solr.properties` (logs for indexator, in this
  case solr4- Alfresco version 5.XX by default)

> take scope on property **log4j.appender.File.File**

- tomcat logs are standard in path which you wrote `./tomcat/logs/`, their path definitions are in `./tomcat/conf/logging.properties`

  - ***1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory***
  - ***2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory***
  - ***3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory***
  - ***4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory***
- `catalina.out` I have found in `./tomcat/bin/catalina.sh`

`if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then
         CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
 fi`

- tomcat access log path is defined in `./tomcat/conf/server.xml`
  look on following

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                   prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                   pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />`

(founded in Alfresco 5.1e- 201602-GA, from .bin linux instalator)

> Btw- I'm not sure, but I think in alf 4.2f Community version for alfresco.log, share.log and solr.log was a rule, that files were in actual directory, from which you were running alfresco.sh startup script

[Source](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/how-better-configure-log)  (forums.alfresco.com)